# Changing algorithm constants of a hash object created by hashlib

Tags: python-3.x, hash, sha256, hashlib

I am wondering if it is possible to modify (by parameter) the hash algorithms of python's *hashlib* library. For example, I would like to run *sha256* with initial hashes that are different to the standard initial hashes of *sha256*.

Now the standard initial hashes are:

```
initHash = [0x6A09E667, 0xBB67AE85, 0x3C6EF372, 0xA54FF53A, 0x510E527F, 0x9B05688C, 0x1F83D9AB, 0x5BE0CD19]
```

I would like to modify this to my own purpose.

Currently, I can do this with the function I have written for *sha256* by my own, but my code runs quite slower than *hashlib*. That is why I would like to use *hashlib* while having access to the parameters.

In other words, I'am asking to see if it is possible in *hashlib* to run a hash algorithm with non-standard user-defined algorithm constants.

Comment: No, it's not possible, and that is a good thing. Providing an interface for casual users to monkey with the innards of such security-critical functions would be a dangerous [attractive nuisance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractive_nuisance_doctrine) and would consitute software malpractice.